# Select component created at runtime

Tags: delphi

What I Want to do:

I create on the run a panel, 2 editfield, a radiobox.
When I Click on the RadioButton `Edit1` I want to have the `Edit1` field visible, and `Edit2` filed Not visible 
and reverse by the click on the RadioButton `Edit2`.

But it doesn't work I probably misunderstand something.
Do you have any idea?

```
procedure CreationPanel(L,T,H,W:integer;Nom,Titre:string
                    {MyPanel:TPanel});                     
begin

MyPanel:=TPanel.Create(Form1);
with MyPanel do
begin
Height:=H;
Left:=L;
Width:=W;
Top:=T;
BorderStyle:=bsSingle;
BevelWidth:=3;
BevelOuter:=bvRaised;
Parent:=Form1;
Visible:=True;
TabOrder:=-1;
TabStop:=False;
Tag:=100;
Name:=Nom;
Caption:=Nom;
end;
end;

procedure Creation_Edit(L,T,FontSize:integer;
                      NomComp,NomPanel:String;
                      Bool:Boolean
                      {MyPanel:Tpanel});
begin  
MyEdit:=TEdit.Create(MyPanel);
with MyEdit do
begin
Parent:=MyPanel;
  {Relation Table Dossier avec Table Bezeichnung}
Height :=21 ;
Left :=L ;
Top :=T ;
Width :=100;
Name:=NomComp;
Font.Name:='MS Sans Serif';
Font.Size:=FontSize;
Visible:=Bool;
end;
end;

procedure Creation_RadioGroup(L,T,H,W,FontSize:integer;
                                    RGName,NomPanel:string
                                    {MyPanelRG:TPanel});
begin  
MyRadioGroup:=TRadioGroup.Create(MyPanel);
with MyRadioGroup do
begin
Parent:=MyPanel;           
Height :=H ;
Left :=L ;
Top :=T ;
Width :=W;
Font.Name:='MS Sans Serif';
Name:=RGName;
Font.Size:=FontSize;
Items.Add('Edit1);
Items.Add('Edit2');
ItemIndex:=0;
OnClick:=Form1.RadioGroupClick;
end;
end;

procedure TForm1.RadioGroupClick(Sender: TObject);
var
E1,E2:TEdit;

begin {1}
E1:=TEdit(FindComponent('Edit1'));
E2:=TEdit(FindComponent('Edit2'));
E1:=TEdit.Create(MyPanel);
E2:=TEdit.Create(MyPanel);

if E1=nil then showmessage('E1=Nil');
if E2=nil then showmessage('E2=Nil');
If MyRadioGroup.Name='RD1' then {with TEDIT}
begin {If}
If Assigned(E1) and Assigned(E2)  then
begin {2}
 Case MyRadioGroup.ItemIndex of
     0: begin
          E1.Visible:=true;
          E2.Visible:=False;
        end;
     1:begin
          E1.Visible:=False;
          E2.Visible:=true;
       end;
  end;{Case}
end;{2}
end;{If}
end;{1}

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin

 {Pannel Left,Top,Hieght,Width}
 CreationPanel(80,100,300,180,'Panel1','Panel 1');
 Creation_Edit(30,184,10,'Edit1','Panel1',true);
 Creation_Edit(30,234,10,'Edit2','Panel1',false);
  {RadioGroup Left,Top,Height,Width,FontSize,Tab}
 Creation_RadioGroup(30,12,90,120,12,'RD1','Panel1');

end;
end.
```

Comment: remove the `E1:=TEdit.Create(MyPanel);` `E2:=TEdit.Create(MyPanel);` and try again

Comment: I already try but then E1 and E2 are Nil.  my problem: how do I assign those two Edits. I try direct by using the name of the Edit I create, but it didn't work. The impression I Have is that the E1.Visible ligne although it compile, the programme don't know what or where it is.

Comment: The code is unreadable because of the lack of indentation, and full of lots of stuff we don't need. No doubt that isn't helping you either. Try again with a minimal example, properly formatted. Also consider debugging your program. And strongly consider thinking a little harder. When `TEdit(FindComponent('Edit1'))` returns `nil`, then you should address that problem rather than just blindly creating another control. Either you want to work with an existing control, or you want to create a new one. Which is it?

Comment: For the intentation, i am sorry but I put 4 spaces at the beginning. In somme case like at the botom I got the intendation right but on the top it didn't work.It should have been wiese to use opening tag and closing tag.
When you use a Component at design time you can write in your code Edti1.name or Edit1.visible etc. But although I name the component, it don't want to accept Edit1 without '' .It tell me Unknown variable. So I try to go around without success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK your code is a complete mess, but I can tell you what your underlying problem is (i.e. the one that caused you to ask the question.)

Firstly Nasreddine is right about removing

```
E1:=TEdit.Create(MyPanel);
E2:=TEdit.Create(MyPanel);
```

That is a complete floundering (try anything) attempt because E1 and E2 return nil.

You should not be trying to stop them being nil. Instead you should ask yourself why they are nil.

And the answer to that is that Edit1 and Edit2 are not owned by Form1. They are owned by MyPanel.

```
MyEdit:=TEdit.Create(MyPanel);
```

So your code should read

```
procedure TForm1.RadioGroupClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  E1,E2:TEdit;

begin {1}
  E1:=TEdit( MyPanel.FindComponent('Edit1'));
  E2:=TEdit(MyPanel.FindComponent('Edit2'));

  if E1=nil then showmessage('E1=Nil');  
  if E2=nil then showmessage('E2=Nil');
  //etc...
end;{1}
```

Comment: That what I was missing.Tanks